# "Routing Error No route matches {}" when omniauth failed on registration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, registration, omniauth

I am using omniauth-identity and configure its "fail on registration".

My files:

config/initializers/omniauth.rb

```
OmniAuth.config.logger = Rails.logger

Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  #...
  provider :identity, on_failed_registration: lambda { |env|
    IdentitiesController.action(:new).call(env)
  }
end
```

config/routes.rb

```
Wie::Application.routes.draw do
  root to: 'categories#index'

  ActiveAdmin.routes(self)
  devise_for :admin_users, ActiveAdmin::Devise.config

  match 'auth/:provider/callback', to: 'sessions#create'
  match 'auth/failure', to: 'sessions#failure'
  match 'signout', to: 'sessions#destroy', as: 'signout'
  resources :identities#, only: [:new]
  resources :categories, path: '', only: [:index] do
    resources :entries, path: '', only: [:index, :show]
  end
end
```

app/controllers/identities_controller.rb

```
class IdentitiesController < ApplicationController
  def new
    ariane.add "New Account"

    @identity = env['omniauth.identity']
  end
end
```

**When I have a failure on registration (passing incorrect mail), I get the following:**

in browser:

> Routing Error
>
> No route matches {} Try running rake routes for more information on
>   available routes.

in server log:

> Started POST "/auth/identity/register" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-07-16
>   17:35:48 +0300    (0.1ms)  begin transaction   Identity Exists (0.2ms)
>   SELECT 1 AS one FROM "identities" WHERE "identities"."email" = 'foo'
>   LIMIT 1    (0.1ms)  rollback transaction Processing by
>   IdentitiesController#new as HTML   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓",
>   "authenticity_token"=>"HIDDEN :)>=",
>   "name"=>"", "email"=>"foo", "password"=>"[FILTERED]",
>   "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]", "commit"=>"Register"}
>   Rendered identities/new.html.erb within layouts/application (11.2ms)
>   Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 44ms
>
> ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches {}):
>   app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:35:in
>   `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb___1224394470845933684_70120630781720'
>   config/initializers/omniauth.rb:8:in`call'
>   config/initializers/omniauth.rb:8:in `block (2 levels) in '
>
> Rendered
>   /Users/ayia/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@global/gems/actionpack-3.2.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/routing_error.erb within rescues/layout (0.6ms)

**What can be the reason for this? What did I wrong?**

**UPDATE**
What I do not understand is - why I get `Started POST "/auth/identity/register"`? According to omniauth configuration I should get the view correspondent to the IdentitiesController.action(:new), i.e. /identities/new ...

Comment: Having the same issue. Did you figure it out? Note that you're receiving a post to that URL because of the form submission. omniauth processes that bit later. In my case, I link to `identities#new`, then fill out the form to register.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have not figured it out yet... So far planning to use ajax for form validation... If you find a solution,  please share:-)

Comment: We had a really silly issue causing it. In a layout that's rendered in that action, a link_to was missing a comma between parameters. Led to that happening oddly enough.

Comment: oh... thanks:) Unfortunately my case is not like yours:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue cannot be reproduced on the 1.1.0 version of omniauth-identiry. So update to latest version fixed the issue.